# How to change HTML Base Element in Silverstripe ran site

Tags: html, silverstripe

I've got a Silverstripe ran site, which I recently added a SSL certificate to.

Because of this I need to change the HTML Base Element to https from http as now none of the images, stylesheets etc linking correctly and are being rejected as they're not being loaded over https.

I cannot find where this is being set.
I've searched the application code and the database and neither are giving me any luck.
It must be pulling http from somewhere - the question is where?

I understand that silverstripe pulls it's base_tag from the HTML base element. 
Does anyone know where this is set for a silverstripe site?

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Just add Director::forceSSL(); to your _config.php

Comment: That crashes the entire site saying that too I was redirected too many times when trying to gain access.

Comment: Try adding `Config::inst()->update('Director', 'alternate_protocol', 'https');` It looks like `Director::is_https()` does not recognise your secure connection, and you get redirection loop 'http -> https -> http ->...'